# Android BLE receive STATE_DISCONNECTED while the device is still connected

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I am developing Android app that connects with BLE device using native BLE API. Many times I receive STATE_DISCONNECTED in the BluetoothGattCallback while the bluetooth device is still connected and can read data from it.

This problem happens mainly on Android 5.0 and later, not happening on earlier versions (4.4 for example). In earlier versions, when STATE_DISCONNECTED is received, it is really disconnected.